# Customer address problems after migration from Magento 1.9.2.4 to Magento 2.3.2

Tags: migration, customer-address, magento2.3.2, magento1.9.2.4

I've searched high and low for a problem the same as this, and while I have found some seemingly similar, after investigating they are not linked.

I migrated fine, and products, categories, attributes etc etc are all there and I can browse the site, however the customer "shipping address" and "billing address" in all areas of the site show as

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}} .......
```

And if I go to "manage addresses" then I also get a fatal error.

When I investigate the eav_attribute_set table, they appear the same as in Magento 1.9.2.4 , which is where I assume the fault lays, because Magento is looking for a different attribute id? Please see below for the table.

Has anyone come across this or solved this? Thanks

[image: Eav Attribute Set table]

Comment: I attempted to strip out the table entries from the M2 table before migration in order to prevent duplicates but this makes no difference either.

Comment: please check your database, the eav_entity_type table. The entity code "customer_address" must have id as 2, because in the \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface, the id of "customer_address" type was fixed to 2 (the ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ADDRESS const). In my case, the "customer_address" entry, somehow changed ID to 4 (it's weird, because the fresh eav_entity_type has the ID column increment as 1,2,3..., but mine 2,4,6,8...). So I need to rewrite the function to use 4 instead of 2 as id, then everything came back to normal.

Comment: Hi Mayur - You are correct, my customer ID is 2 and customer_address ID is 12.
My concern in altering this is will this not affect future updates?
Thank you

Comment: I don't this this will affect @steve